# Git problems with line endings differences between linux and windows

Tags: linux, windows, git, newline, core.autocrlf

I'm working on a project on Windows and some project files seems to be changed locally but I didn't. Was ignoring them but now I cannot push because are unstaged files. When I look into this files differences, there isn't, only this line ending thing (CRLF, LF).

Tried to revert this files, reset --hard too.

Why can't I reset this files to repository HEAD?

Tried to do this too:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

If I do git reset --hard and git status later I get message that have many files with changes not staged.

Sorry but I don't know git and this linux/windows line ending differences very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe someone else working on the project introduced bad line endings. two things 2 do:

1. fix bad line endings already committed.
2. align the team about the line endings policy.

See: [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/).

Comment: My team is using linux. I'm using Windows with a linux VM. The link helped me. Thanks.